# Get two sums from Room database

Tags: android, android-room

I have two tables in Room and I need to get from them two sums.
I know how to get it from one table, but I can't find the solution of my problem.

```
@Query("SELECT COALESCE(sum(COALESCE(value,0)), 0) FROM expense_table ")
LiveData<Double> getTotalValue();
```

My second table is an income_table

Comment: how about writing two queries and sum their result?

Comment: And there is reason of the problem. I need two sums in one query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `SELECT (SELECT SUM(value) FROM expense_table) + (SELECT SUM(value) FROM income_table)`

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hZKphYCL5S8Jt6tWnpdqCP/0